# SAS: assigned character value gets reduced

Tags: sas

In a data step process, I create a new variable with character value. However, character values in the output data  got reduced from `"CL_FA_IF"` to `"CL"`. What is the problem?

```
else if var in ("CL", "FA", "IF") then var2 = "CL_FA_IF"
```

Comment: How did you define VAR2?  If you do not explicitly define your variables before using them in the code then SAS will be forced to GUESS how to define them by how they are first used.  So where is VAR2 first referenced in the data step?

Comment: Yes. you are right. It was assigned with 2 character value in the last line. I will define the length then. Thank you!